# SpriteKit Objective Jump

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I got a problem with my code. I added the swipe gesture to jump, but my objective won't jump at all. The NSLog for the Swipe gesture works, so it must be something wrong with my objective code.

```
-(void)Mensch{

SKTexture * MenschTexture1 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Mensch1"];
MenschTexture1.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
SKTexture * MenschTexture2 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Mensch2"];
MenschTexture2.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;

SKAction * Run = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction animateWithTextures:@[MenschTexture1, MenschTexture2] timePerFrame:0.4]];

Mensch = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:MenschTexture1];
Mensch.size = CGSizeMake(45, 45);
Mensch.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 5, Boden.position.y + 73);
Mensch.zPosition = 2;

Mensch.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:Mensch.size];
Mensch.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
Mensch.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
Mensch.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
Mensch.physicsBody.restitution = 0;

[Mensch runAction:Run];
[self addChild:Mensch];

}


- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
recognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
}

- (void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender
{ 
Mensch.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0);
[Mensch.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0, 20)];

NSLog(@"Jump");

}
```

Comment: You need to set Mensch.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;

Comment: Something so simple, and I didnt see it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Great! Have added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set

```
Mensch.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
```

According to Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/dynamic) about the `dynamic` property of `SKPhysicsBody`:

> The default value is YES. If the value is NO, then the physics body
>   ignores all forces and impulses applied to it. This property is
>   ignored on edge-based bodies; they are automatically static.